# How to execute a function after Jquery callbacks inside .each loop have comepleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, devexpress, each

I have a function that calls JQuery.each(). It then calls a third party function,(Devexpress GetRowValues()), that executes a callback.
After the .each has finished, I have to call DoSuccess() and pass in the array rv.
The problem is that RVGridCB() executes after DoSuccess(). How can I ensure that all callbacks within the .each loop are done before I execute DoSuccess()?

```
function ReturnValueAndClose(ctrl) {
    var rv = new Array();

    $('[id*="chkCopy"]').each(function () {
        try {
            var v = $(this).val();
            if (v == 'C') {               
                var id = eval($(this)[0].id).id;
                var i = id.indexOf('chkCopy_') + 8;               
                var rowIndex = parseInt(id.substr(i, 4));
                 wgdFormFile.GetRowValues(rowIndex, "Name;Description;Details", RVGridCB);           
            }

        } catch (e) {
        }

    });   

     function RVGridCB(values) {           
            rv.push(values);  
        }

     DoSuccess(new Array('1', rv));
     return false;    
}
```

Comment: jQuery's .each is by definition synchronous, but anything that is called in it that is asynchronous does not block .each from completing. It seems like wgdFormFile.getRowValues is asynchronous in your block of code above.  I'd need to know a little bit more about that function to make a good recommendation

Comment: The documentation for GetRowValues can be found at : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGridView_GetRowValuestopic

Comment: one second. i'm typing something out

Comment: @deweyredman I had attempted to use something similar to the answer you had posted. You got me thinking about my logic and deferred objects and then the current answer came along.

Comment: Yeah, that is a much much better approach :)

Comment: I should thank you, as this answer/the poster below got me insanely curious about promise objects and deferred objects so I've been reading up on them a lot to see if there is any way I can refactor my code using them.  Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could work with [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) objects.

Create an array with deferred objects for each callback `RVGridCB` and inside of the callback call `dfd.resolve()`.

In the done callback `$.when.apply($, deferred_arr).done(function () ...);` you can call `doSuccess(...)`.

Here is a deferred example with timeouts to simulate the asynchronous events. You can also find it here at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jyf3qmqn/).

---

**Edit 04.02.2015:**

I have added a done callback to each deffered object to better show the end of each timeout.

```js
var asyncEvent = function (n) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var duration = n * 1000;

    setTimeout(function () {
        dfd.resolve(n);
    }, duration);
    
    dfd.done(function(n) {
        var now = new Date();
        //console.log('end time', n, now);
        $('body').append('end time of task ' + n + ': '+ now.toString() + '<br/>');
    });
    
    return dfd;
};

var thingsToDo = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var def = [];

var events = function () {
    $.each(thingsToDo, function (index, value) {
        var now = new Date();
        $('body').append('start time: ' + now.toString() + '<br/>');
        //console.log('called', value);
        def.push(asyncEvent(value));
    });
    return def;
};

$.when.apply($, events())
    .done(function (status) {
    //console.log(def);
    var now = new Date();
    console.log('end time', now);
    $('body').append('end time: ' + now.toString() + '<br/>');
    $('body').append('all events done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: wasn't actually aware of these...this is a much better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Look at jquery Deferred object.

If your GetRowValues method returns Deferred object, you may try to store them in an array

```
var valuesDone = [];

$('[id*="chkCopy"]').each(function(){

    valuesDone.push( 
        wgdFormFile.GetRowValues(rowIndex, "Name;Description;Details").done(RVGridCB) 
    );

})
```

After that, using jquery '$.when()' method, you set a callback when all 'values are done'.

```
$.when.apply($, valuesDone).done(function(){ DoSuccess(new Array('1', rv)); })
```

If your GetRowValues method **doesn't return Deferred**, you can make facade function:

```
function GetRowValues(rowIndex){
    var d = new $.Deferred();
    wgdFormFile.GetRowValues(rowIndex, "Name;Description;Details", function(){ d.resolve() });
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, why don't you comment what's wrong with my solution?